# Why results based on padding generally fail to relativize?

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines, relativization

I have read in the [Algebrization paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20200320092926id_/http://cse.ucdenver.edu/%7Ecscialtman/complexity/Algebrization%20-%20A%20New%20Barrier%20in%20Complexity%20Theory.pdf) that, if we only allow polynomially-long queries to oracles, then, results based on padding will not relativize. For instance: assuming that $A$ is a PSPACE-complete language, $P^A = NP^A$ does not imply $EXP^{A[poly]} = NEXP^{A[poly]}$ (unless $EXP$ = $NEXP$).

However, I do not see why the padding argument is not valid under oracles with polynomially-long queries.

In essence, assuming that we have a non-deterministic turing machine $M$ (running in EXP time) that calls some oracle $A$ (using only polynomially-long queries), it seems to me that a non-deterministic turing machine $M'$ having access to the same oracle $A$ (with the same polynomially-long queries limitation) can simulate $M$ in PTIME (considering that the input has been padded exponentially). From there, using that $P^A$ = $NP^A$, it seems possible to me to end with $EXP^{A[poly]} = NEXP^{A[poly]}$, which is not the case according to the paper.

Can someone explain me what I am missing, please?